# Calculating torque from what a winch can lift

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, rotational-dynamics, torque

I am curious about the relationship between torque and how far something gets lifted by say, a motor. Let's say I have a small motor, and I geared it up so that the gear ratio is 10:1.

I use it to lift a brick that masses 2 kg about 20 cm. The change in potential energy of the brick is

$\Delta PE = mgh = (2kg)(9.8 m/s^2)(0.2m) = 3.92 J.$

Joules are Newton-meters as well (the old force x distance relation for Work) and my thought was that if the motor is adding that much PE -- doing that much work -- we could back-calculate the original torque. Since energy is conserved (and torque is in the same units, newton-meters) it would follow that we applied 3.92 J of torque and could use that output torque to find the input torque using the gear ratio.

However, I recalled that torque is force x *radius* and therefore it's just simpler to measure the radius of the winch/wheel that is pulling our mass and use the force from the brick to get the (output) torque. But I was curious if my initial intuition was at all sensible.

Answer (score 1):

> Since energy is conserved (and torque is in the same units, newton-meters) it would follow that we applied 3.92 J of torque

This intuition is understandable but incorrect. Adding 3.92 J of potential energy to the object can be accomplished with any amount of torque, not necessarily 3.92 Nm.

For example, we could apply a tiny torque (keeping the force equal to $mg$ but making the arm tiny) and a large angle of rotation or, conversely, a large torque but a tiny angle of rotation.

This shows that the amount of added energy does not directly determine the amount of torque, even though they have the same units.

Comment: thanks that helps. I was thinking about setting up student labs, is all, and given that I am working with kids absent calculus or even second-year algebra I was curious about simple ways for them to build stuff but also get a sense of a wee bit of the physics/ engineering.